# Identify this item clicked on trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that is usually clicked by the user.  It executes a function

```
$('.MenuItem').click(function() {
 document.writeln($(this).html() + ' was clicked');   
});
```

I have run into a new requirement where I need to trigger the click of a menu item programmatically.  So I tried

```
//I want to trigger click and identify the item that has been clicked. Normally, I just use 
//the this object, but on a trigger I don't know how to assign this so `.html()` functions.

//This doesn't work as intended.   
//$('.MenuItem').trigger('click','Item1');
```

How can I identify the item clicked on `trigger`?
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/yNg5E/)

Comment: sure it does http://jsfiddle.net/bMLUn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in a number of ways.  If you just want to use an index and click based on that:

```
$(".MenuItem").eq(1).click();
```

You could also give them each an ID and click based on the ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.MenuItem').trigger('click'); //will trigger click event on all elements with .MenuItem ClassName
```

You need to be more specific such as using an element id

```
$('#MenuItemID1').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.MenuItem:nth-child(1)').trigger('click');
```

as mentioned you need to specify which element is taking the trigger.

```
$('.MenuItem').trigger('click');
```

will in fact trigger the click on both elements. 
 [James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053640/identify-this-item-clicked-on-trigger/8053709#8053709) answer will work as well. (without altering markup)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using an index. Based on your html, get the index of the clicked element, then trigger the click event of the target element that also has that given index.

Generally, to get the index of an element, you use `.index()`, and to select an element by it's index, you use `.eq()`. Since you didn't post html, I wont be posting a complete sample.